# Transfer data between angular components using @input and @output

Tags: angular, input, components, output, data-transfer

I have two components sitting one in another.

```
    settings folder
      |--settings.component.css
      |--settings.component.html
      |--settings.component.ts
      |-- userPRofile folder
            |-- userProfile.component.css
            |-- userProfile.component.html
            |-- userProfile.component.ts
```

Now in settings component, I get some data with function while OnInit.

```
    this.service.getUserSettings().subscribe(
       res => {
         this.userSettings = res;
```

And now I want this data to be sent to the userProfile component. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you share the template of settings component ?

Comment: Please share your Html and ts file, so that we can provide a straight solution

Comment: In question , you can see settings.ts part where I get res variable and put it inside this.userSettings. Now I want userProfile.ts to get that userSettings variable that's all. consider clean userProfile.ts file for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need use property binding to pass the data to child component

*settings component template*

```
<app-user-profile [data]="userSettings"></app-user-profile>
```

*userProfile.ts*

```
@Input() data:any;
```

now the value from the `userSettings` will pass to the `data` property.

Comment: I want to use data from settings component inside userProfile component. Can you write more detailed example? I cannot understand this one

Comment: from the parent component, you can pass data to child component <app-user-profile [data]="userSettings "></app-user-profile> is child component and parent component is passing data , userSettings dirctly pass to child .

Comment: @David I have update  the answer is it still not clear ?

Comment: As I understand settings component is html file ? But I want something different I think. I mean I create some variable in settings.ts file and want to use it in userProfile.ts How to send from settings.ts>userProfile.ts ????

Comment: is userProfile is child inside settings setting template or not

Comment: Yes I have settings folder and inside that folder I have userProfile.
Variable is generated in settings.ts file and I want to use it in userProfile.ts

Comment: is userProfile inside the template (html file) of settings ?

Comment: @David check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pr6rpd

Comment: I've updated question now you can see all folders and files there

Comment: I see it works but I don't understand how @Input() user:any; gets data from  userData ??? It just simply gets everything that is exported from all components ??? if so how can it get only specific data ?

Comment: check setting template file ` [user]="userData"`

Comment: Ok I understand. Problem is that you put userProfile inside settings template.
And I want userProfile to work independently from settings component at all. Just want to send data from one .ts file to another .ts file

Comment: I accepted the answer, just want a hint how to send from one .ts to another .ts without using templates ?

Comment: you can use global service in that case

Comment: ok thnx. As I understand if I want to transfer some data from one .ts to another .ts then I must use some service. thnx

Answer (score 1):

```
In settings component template html User
<app-user-profile (open)="onOpen($event)"  [data]="userSettings"></app-user-profile>
 onOpen():void{
// code goes here
}

In UserProfile.ts 
@Input() data:any;
@Output() open: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```