# component interaction in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I have two components in angular8. `1) add-files component 2) Discussion Component.`

In the discussion component, I am having one button (see below)

```
<app-add-files></app-add-files>

<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" (click)="removeitems()" class="greenBtn float-right addCommentsBtn"
              [disabled]="commentForm.pristine || commentForm.invalid" onclick="closeCommnetPopupBox()">
          </div>
```

I want to call a function `removedoc()` that is defined in the add-files component whenever I clicked on the button that is defined in the discussion component.

I tried with the below approach.

I import the add-files component in the discussion component and created an object of the same and then calling the function from the discussion component to the add-files component.

```
removeitems()
{
 this.comp.removedoc();
}
```

comp is the object created of the add-files component.

I was doing some research on the internet and found that we can achieve this with `@input/@output` decorators with `event emitters`.

I am new to Angular. can anyone suggest me this approach to how to trigger the function form different components using `event emitters` with `@input/@output` in Angular?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you post an example of your component structure as things stand. For example, `<discussion></discussion><add-files></add-files>` @Input / @Output is the way to go though.

Comment: Please read this for more details https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#how-to-use-output

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901770/transfer-data-between-angular-components-using-input-and-output?noredirect=1&lq=1 and here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vts7zd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts

Comment: Are they parent child component

Comment: @MustafaKunwa Yes they are parent-child component

Comment: @MustafaKunwa please see my updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the child component class using **ViewChild** decorator.

```js
// Inside parent component.
@ViewChild('mychild') childComponent: Component2;
  onButtonClick() {

   // Exceute the function of child class.
   console.log( this.childComponent.method1());
  }

// On parent component html.
<component2 #mychild></component2>
```

You can play with it [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grjjb4?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)